# How I can fix this statement, my code does not work with tensorflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, linear-regression

I have some problems in my code, but I can not know how to fix it. I have target: y = x/3 - 8. Input: X_train: an array of floats from -10 to 10, Y_train: an array is created from target and a little bit noise I added. I used gradient descent for optimization of loss function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import sklearn as skl
import scipy as sci
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib as mplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fun(x):
    return (1.0/3.0)*x - 8;
def generate_data(N):
    X_train = np.random.uniform(-10, 10 , size = N);
    #print(X_train);
    Y_train = fun(X_train) + X_train/50;#X_train/50 la tao noise
    #print(fun(X_train))
    #print(Y_train);
    return X_train, Y_train;

X_train, Y_train = generate_data(100);
print(X_train[0:5])
print(Y_train[0:5])
#plt.scatter(x = X_train, y = Y_train)
#target: y = x/3 - 8
W = tf.Variable([np.random.random()],dtype = tf.float32);
b = tf.Variable([np.random.random()],dtype = tf.float32);
X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32);
Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32);
#-----------------------------------------
linear_model = W*X + b;
#-----------------------------------------
loss_value = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(linear_model - Y));
#-------------------------------------------
gradient_op = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01);
train =  gradient_op.minimize(loss_value);
init = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(init) # reset values to wrong
#--------------------------------------------
for i in range(1000):
    sess.run(train, {X:X_train, Y:Y_train})
#-------------------------------------------------
curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss = sess.run([W, b, loss_value], {X:X_train, Y:Y_train})
print("W: %s b: %s loss: %s"%(curr_W, curr_b, curr_loss))
#RESULT: W: [nan] b: [nan] loss: nan
```

Answer (score 1):

if you move the `print()` line in the for-loop you can get a better idea of what's going on:

```
W: [18.353216] b: [-16.890762] loss: 1247183.4
W: [-1346.8429] b: [24.758984] loss: 6829195000.0
W: [99991.945] b: [-1827.1696] loss: 37613004000000.0
W: [-7420763.] b: [134402.12] loss: 2.0716051e+17
W: [5.507228e+08] b: [-9974508.] loss: 1.14097444e+21
W: [-4.087121e+10] b: [7.402444e+08] loss: 6.284125e+24
W: [3.0332058e+12] b: [-5.4936326e+10] loss: 3.4610951e+28
W: [-2.2510564e+14] b: [4.0770313e+12] loss: 1.9062617e+32
W: [1.6705936e+16] b: [-3.0257186e+14] loss: 1.0499083e+36
W: [-1.2398103e+18] b: [2.245499e+16] loss: inf
W: [9.201099e+19] b: [-1.6664696e+18] loss: inf
W: [-6.828481e+21] b: [1.2367498e+20] loss: inf
W: [5.0676726e+23] b: [-9.178383e+21] loss: inf
W: [-3.7609104e+25] b: [6.8116245e+23] loss: inf
W: [2.791113e+27] b: [-5.0551633e+25] loss: inf
W: [-2.07139e+29] b: [3.7516253e+27] loss: inf
W: [1.5372564e+31] b: [-2.7842225e+29] loss: inf
W: [-1.14085575e+33] b: [2.066276e+31] loss: inf
W: [8.46672e+34] b: [-1.5334612e+33] loss: inf
W: [-inf] b: [1.1380394e+35] loss: inf
```

You can see that the loss is "exploding". This is a simple example of the [exploding gradient problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem).

You can read up on potential solutions but the simplest for a toy example might be to reduce your learning rate.

Intuitively, gradient descent is like trying to find your way to the valley floor by pointing in the downhill direction and taking a step, then repeat. At each stage you re-evaluate the direction based on what is downhill now. If the valley is smooth with no local low-spots and your step size is small enough you will eventually find the bottom.

The learning rate is analogous with the size of the step.

So, with too high a learning rate, you can now imagine you are taking such a large step that you step right across the whole valley to a point higher up the hill on the opposite side. Then you turn in order to point downhill again (so roughly a 180 turn) and face the centre of the valley but step right across to even higher up the other side. And so on getting higher and higher up the opposite sides of the valley

So, dramatically reducing your learning rate to something like this seems to allow it to converge:

```py
...
gradient_op = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.0001)
...
```

```
W: [0.35333326] b: [-7.999988] loss: 1.4234502e-08
```